# When same-named namespaces exist (in current scope), how to refer any of them?

Tags: c#

I have:

```
namespace Book {
   ...
}

    ...
    ...



namespace Company 
{ 
    public class Book {

    }
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
    public class MyBook : Book.smth
    {
    }
}
```

How I make it, as `MyBook` to inherit the top-level `Book` namespace, instead of `Company`'s ?

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a perfectly sensible question.

Comment: could you rename it and reference it? using topLevel = xyz.DefaultClass;      topLevel.method();

Comment: @EricLippert Thanks Eric, I am used to downvotes, just because I am new to C#, and my questions are quite easy for others.

Comment: The unfortunate situation you're in is not very common, and the remedies are by no means obvious.

Comment: @JoshAdams you could have posted that as answer, thanks!

Comment: Dang, maybe next time! looks like Eric already added my suggestion with an explanation in his answer as well. Anyways, best of luck to you on your coding journey!

Comment: @EricLippert i dont know if its common or not, but i see myself in that situation frequently. here my every-day example, again  - https://stackoverflow.com/q/49722747/2377343 . The question has 4 downvotes, with CLOSE mark.  really dont know why. maybe i am vague still? O_o

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First off, ideally you do not get into this bad situation in the first place.  Try to name your namespaces and classes so that they don't conflict with those of your dependencies!  But sometimes it is unavoidable, particularly when a dependency adds a feature that you already implemented.

---

Technique #1:

You can do that with the `global::` modifier.

```
namespace Company 
{ 
  namespace Xyz 
  { 
    public class DefaultClass {} 
  }
  public class myClass: global::Xyz.DefaultClass
```

Now `Xyz.DefaultClass` refers to the *top level* `Xyz.DefaultClass`, not `Company.Xyz.DefaultClass`

---

Technique #2:

Use a *using alias directive*, either on the namespace:

```
using TheOtherXyz = Xyz;
namespace Company {
  namespace Xyz 
  { 
    public class DefaultClass {} 
  }
  public class MyClass : TheOtherXyz.DefaultClass
```

or on the class:

```
using TheOtherDefault = Xyz.DefaultClass;
namespace Company {
  namespace Xyz 
  { 
    public class DefaultClass {} 
  }
  public class MyClass : TheOtherDefault
```

Note that the second variation does *not* work on generic classes. You can say

```
using StringList = System.Collections.Generic.List<String>
```

but you cannot say

```
using MyList<T> = System.Collections.Generic.List<T>
```

to make a generic alias.  It's a perfectly sensible feature, it's just never been high priority enough to add it.

---

A question you didn't ask, but I'll answer it anyways:

> What if I have namespace `N` with class `C` in two different assemblies that I am referencing?  `N.C` is now ambiguous and `global::` doesn't help, and neither does a using alias directive.

In that unfortunate case you use an *extern alias directive*, which you can read about here.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/extern-alias

---

If you are interested in other things that can go horribly wrong when you have a name collision like this, see my articles on that subject here:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/tag/namespaces/

Comment: Great explanation Eric. I wanted to work on providing an alias answer but you did a great job covering it already. I appreciate you taking the time to point out the possible conflicts you may run into, very helpful! Best of luck.