# Is variable's value back-slashing available in PHP?

Tags: php

When we check:

```
dir1/dir2/../file.txt  ==== this is same as =====>   dir1/file.txt
```

I am interested is something same thing available in PHP, like:

```
$name= "Hello ". $variable . "World";
```

if i had `$variable = "../Hi"` (or anything like that) so, it removed (like backslashing) the previous part, printed `Hi World`  ?

(p.s. I dont control the php file, I ask about how attackers can achieve that).

(p.s.2. I dont have words to downvoters for closing this. I think you have problems with analysing of questions before you close).

Comment: `$name= "Hello ". $variable . "World";` printed `Hi World`? That's not possible, so can you edit and make your info clear please? Also, make your question a little clearer. And what is `$variable` being set to?

Comment: Of course not. A path is not the same as string concatenation. You would need a function to parse variable and string

Comment: I'm assuming you want to remove the prior word and it's `/` for each occurance of `../`?

Comment: Hi, using `.` concatenate operator? No it's impossible (unless you have a way to hack PHP :D), though you can manage to do it using a function with parameters, but personally don't see any benefit, since `..` is something related to Linux (or Unix) and point to parent directory...

Comment: not clear what you want, how does  `"Hello ". $variable . "World"` turn in to `Hi World` with this being the only input `$variable = "../Hi"`?

Comment: I think the OP is concerned someone might be able to post some content that, when interpolated with other string content, simply by concatenating or "otherwise operating on the string" (the directory operation is handled by the filesystem), what was interpolated could change the character of the content it was joined with or the expression it encompasses. I think you're overthinking it.

Comment: @JaredFarrish yeh, you understood it. but seems there doesnt exist any of simbol like that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `PHP` there exist no special `../` (or any other string) that when concatenated to another string generates any string other than the combine original string concatenated with the new string.  Concatenation, regardless of content of strings always results in:

```
"<String1><String2>" = "<String1>"."<String2>";
```

Nothing will not 'erase' prior tokens in a string or anything like that and is completely harmless.

**Caveat!!!!** Of course if the string is being used somewhere that interprets it in some specific way where any character or group of characters in the `../` is treated special such as:

- In a string used for regex pattern
- In a string used as a file path (in that case, when it's evaluated it will do exactly what you'd expect if you'd typed it.
- A string used in a SQL query without properly escaping (as with binding params/values via prepared statements)
- etc...

Now, if you want to remove the word prior to each occurence of `../` starting a word in a sentence, sort-of replicating how the `..` in a path means, go up one level (in effect undoing the step made to the directory in the path prior to it).

Here's a basic algorithm to start you out (if you are able to change the source code) :

- Use explode with delimiter `" "` on the string.
- Create a new array
- Iterate the returned array, if not `../` insert at end of new array
- if entry starts with `../`, remove the end element of the 2nd array
- insert the the `../somestring` with the `../` string replaced with empty string `""` on the end of the 2nd array
- Once at end of array (all strings processed), `implode()` with delimiter `" "`

Here's an example:

```
<?php

$variable = "../Hi";
$string = "Hello ". $variable . " World"; // Note: I added a space prior to the W 

$arr = array();

foreach(explode(" ", $string) as $word) {
   if (substr( $word, 0, 3 ) === "../") {
      if(!empty($arr)){
         array_pop($arr);
      }
      $arr[] =  str_replace("../", "", $word);
   } else {
      $arr[] = $word;
   }
}

echo implode(" ", $arr);
```

Comment: Thank, you understood exactly what i meant, but the question relates - who to do it (when I dont control the php file). I mean, what can attacker can use to achieve. I thought I should have asked on security.se, but preferred here.

Comment: Oh.  No, `../` does nothing special in a string itself, see my update for 2 cases you might want to watch out for if you then use the string with it in it.

Comment: @T.Todua does that answer your question?

Comment: thank you for the effort, but to say frankly, my main concern was to know if there exists any string (not exactly `../` which you are concentrated. I just asked that as an example, because didnt know other example to express my idea. so, my question was general , if there exists any of like that string, which could cause to erase previous characters/word (without regex, just with simple concatenation).

Comment: Ah, I get it.  No, nothing in string concatenation ever occurs except a new string that is exactly the concatenated characters of the original strings.  See my new update to the question.